# How do I format boxouts in css

Tags: css

I'm writing some documentation for some VBA code I wrote, and I'm trying to add boxouts for comments to add notes. In the past I've always just floated them off to the right, but now that I need to comment sequential lines there's not always enough space for the comment on a single line. The upshot is that the comments end up staggered horizontally to fit them all in.

[image: staggered versus stacked boxouts]

What I'd like to do is make the boxouts stack and make the text they're floated next to shuffle down a bit to make space.

Can it be done? My HTML/CSS skills are a bit rusty and from the 4.01 days...

EDIT: There's not much code to show - so far I only have this:

```
.boxcomment {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

That successfully stacks the boxouts, but they end up misaligned with the associated code line.

EDIT: Here's an example of the alignment issue:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calculator Documentation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Header -->

<!-- Navigation -->

<!-- Content -->

<div style="width:40%;">

<div class="boxcomment">Comment is way too long Comment is way too long Comment is way too long Comment is way too long </div>
<pre>Some random code and some more code</pre>
<div class="boxcomment">Another comment</div>
<pre>More code</pre>

</div>

<!-- Footer -->

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.boxcomment {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px #000;
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

That gives this result, where the second comment isn't aligned with the paragraph it accompanies. (Coloured lines indicate where they should line up.)

[image: Showing misaligned text]

Does that make the question any clearer? It's a bit fuzzy, I know...

EDIT: Expanded the HTML by request to include the whole code.

Comment: code! baby, code???

Comment: Talk is cheap. Show me the code - Linus Torvalds

Comment: Not much to show, but I've added the code I have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use clearance:

> [**9.5.2 Controlling flow next to floats: the 'clear' property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#flow-control)
>
> This property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may not be
>   adjacent to an earlier floating box.
>
> Values other than 'none' potentially introduce *clearance*. Clearance
>   inhibits margin collapsing and acts as spacing above the margin-top of
>   an element. It is used to push the element vertically past the float.

Like this:

```css
clear: right;
```

```css
.boxcomment {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  border: 1px #000;
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 10px;
}
pre::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxcomment">Comment is way too long Comment is way too long Comment is way too long Comment is way too long </div>
<pre>Some random code and some more code</pre>
<div class="boxcomment">Another comment</div>
<pre>More code</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks - that solves the stacking issue. Is there any way to force the body text to follow it down?

Comment: I'll add an example to the question.

Comment: It would be clearer if you showed all the code especially in a pen.

Comment: @AndrewPerry Since you mix the floats with the non-floats like this without containers it's a bit trickier but you can add a pseudo-element with clearance.

Comment: Done. Adding your revised code now to see what happens.